# Django Rest Framework redirects to GET after a failed POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to POST to a Django Rest Framework API View page. The server is running on localhost, and DEBUG=True. I get a 500 error, but it immediately redirects to GET the same page, providing me with no helpful error debugging information.

```
[16/Jan/2016 19:07:00] "POST /account/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 12031
[16/Jan/2016 19:07:00] "GET /account/create/ HTTP/1.1" 405 4810
```

So instead of getting any helpful information about fixing my 500 error, all I get is a page saying "Method GET not allowed." Anyway to fix this?

Here's the code:

```
class CreateAccount(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
  try:
    print Account.objects.get(username="reparadocs")
    account = Account.objects.get(username=serializer.data['username'])
  except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    account = Account.objects.create_user(
      serializer.data['username'],
      '',
      serializer.data['password']
    )
    token = Token.objects.create(user=account)
    return Response({'token': token[0].key}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  return Response({'errors': 'Username already exists'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Problems were with version 3.3.2, Works perfectly with 3.2.5... Have no idea why though :/